# Properly wrap child control's property in a UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class that inherits from `UserControl` that as a component has a `TextBox` control. I want to override the `Text` property of my user control to instead use my text box's text. I originally had this inside my user control:

```
public override string Text
{
    get { return textBox.Text; }
    set { textBox.Text = value; }
}
```

But then I realized I also had to do this in order to work with other features of other controls:

```
void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnTextChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

So my question is, is there anything else I need to do for my `Text` property to behave just as if it were the text box's text property? And is this the right way to do it?

Comment: is there any matter with publishing the textbox as a property?

Comment: I think there is no any other.